# Wrong result SoapVar

Tags: php, api

I am trying to post my SoapHeader with the function 'SoapVar'. When I print the information of the variable I can see that the data that is posted is not correct:

```
SoapHeader Object
(
    [namespace] => http://www.example.com/
    [name] => Header
    [data] => SoapVar Object
        (
            [enc_type] => 147
            [enc_value] => xxx
        )

    [mustUnderstand] => 
)
```

The [data] that has type `SoapVar Object`. The [data] has also the objects `[enc_type] => 147` and `[enc_value] => xxx`. I dont know what these objects mean, but the result I get is: "the access token is missing".

I get this result when I use the following script:

```
$headerVar = new SoapVar('<Header><Header><AccessToken>xxx</AccessToken></Header></Header>', XSD_ANYXML);                   
$header = new SoapHeader('http://www.example.com/', 'Header', $headerVar);
```

When I try to work with a array, instead of a XML call I get the following SoapHeader:

```
SoapHeader Object
(
    [namespace] => http://www.example.com/
    [name] => Header
    [data] => Array
        (
            [AccessToken] => xxx
        )

    [mustUnderstand] => 
)
```

The script that I use for this result is:

```
$header = new SoapHeader('http://www.example.com/', 'Header', array('AccessToken' =>'xxx'));
```

Does someone know what I need to change to get the script with `SoapVar` working?

Here is my full script:

```
$cluster = $result->cluster;
$qq = new domDocument();
$qq->loadXML($session->__getLastResponse());
$newurl = $cluster.'/services/process.asmx?wsdl';
try
{
    $client = new SoapClient($newurl);

    $headerVar = new SoapVar('<Header><Header><AccessToken>xxx</AccessToken></Header></Header>', XSD_ANYXML);                   
    $header = new SoapHeader('http://www.example.com/', 'Header', $headerVar);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
    echo 'Header: <br />';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($header);
    echo '</pre>';
}
catch (SoapFault $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
try
{
    echo '<br /><br />XML Result:<br /><br />';
    $xml = "";
    $result = $client->__soapCall('ProcessXmlString', array(array('xmlRequest'=>$xml)), null, $header);
    echo '<xmp>';
    print_r($result->ProcessXmlStringResult);
    echo '</xmp>';
}
catch (SoapFault $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Are you really passing `xxx` as the token or did you do that just to protect you real token

Comment: Should there really be 2 of these `<Header><Header>` at the front of your SoapVar?

Comment: I did it to protect my real token. The  `<Header><Header>` are necessary for the script. I also tried it with 1x `<Header>` and without `<Header><Header>`. The result is the same.

Comment: Have you tried creating your `$headerVar` using an alternate call to `SoapVar`? For example: `$headerVar = new SoapVar('xxx', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'AccessToken' );`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current code is that you are not setting the node name.
That is the reason why your data (enc_value) is present but your node name (enc_name) is missing

```php
$headerVar = new SoapVar('<Header><Header><AccessToken>xxx</AccessToken></Header></Header>', XSD_ANYXML, null, null, 'AccessToken');                   
$header = new SoapHeader('http://www.example.com/', 'Header', $headerVar);
```

this would output:

```php
SoapHeader Object
(
    [namespace] => http://www.example.com/
    [name] => Header 
    [data] => SoapVar Object
        (
            [enc_type] => 147
            [enc_value] =>
xxx
            [enc_name] => AccessToken
         )
    [mustUnderstand] => 
)
```

Please be aware that although you only see the 'xxx' value, the rest of your XML data is present. If I do a var_dump I can see that the 'enc_value' == string(64)

I don't know what your endpoint is expecting so that part might need some tweaking.